# Missing library in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, libraries, shared-library

A package that I want to use needs a shared library called `libCGAL.so.13`. When I run it, I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libCGAL.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I try to install it using `$ sudo apt install libcgal13`, apt is unable to locate the package.

After some research, I figured that libcgal13 is no longer available in Ubuntu 20.04. And that the last version that still has this package is Ubuntu 18.04.

Can I download this library somewhere without using `apt` (and just putting the `.so` file in my `/usr/lib/` directory). If not, is there a way to install a package from previous releases ?

**EDIT:**

Output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sublime-text.list:deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/ # 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openjdk-r-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu disco main #
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openjdk-r-ubuntu-ppa-disco.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu disco main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntugis-ubuntu-ubuntugis-unstable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu focal main
```

**EDIT 2:**

I was able to make it work by compiling the library from source and using `ldconfig` afterwards as @llywrch suggested.

Comment: What happens if you copy that file from a system running Ubuntu 18.04? (If you do this, remember to run ldconfig afterwards.) Otherwise, the package maintainer should be the one with a solution.

Comment: Please add output of `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"` to the question.

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for libcgal13 on ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 1):

The package is available in 18.04 LTS [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libCGAL.so.13) from *universe* [pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libcgal13).

You have to add the repository with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the 64-bit library with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcgal13
```

If you know that application is 32-bit - use additional command:

```
sudo apt-get install libcgal13:i386
```

Comment: When I use `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, It outputs that `universe` is already active. And `apt` is still unable to locate the package.

Answer (score 0):

`libcgal13` does appear to be missing from the 20.04 universe repo, but is present in the 18.04 repo [as shown here

**Workarounds**

1. Contact the package maintainer and ask them to publish to 20.04

You can find contact information of the maintainers [in the changelog](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/libcgal13_4.11-2build1_amd64.deb.html)

2. Download the package from the 18.04 repo and manually install

This is not recommended for production servers or publishing packages, but may be acceptable as a temporary solution.

3. Try using one of the similarly named packages. Specifically `libcgal-dev` or `libcgal-qt5-dev`

```
apt search libcgal       
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libcgal-demo/focal 5.0.2-3 all
  C++ library for computational geometry (demos)

libcgal-dev/focal,now 5.0.2-3 amd64 [installed]
  C++ library for computational geometry (development files)

libcgal-ipelets/focal 5.0.2-3 amd64
  C++ library for computational geometry (ipelets)

libcgal-qt5-dev/focal 5.0.2-3 amd64
  C++ library for computational geometry (development files, support for Qt5)
```